# MacBook Air 2011 release , OS recovery

Tags: apple-inc

I formatted my hard disk in internet recovery (disk utility) but it had a partition so I can't boot into the main disk all I see is APPLE SSD HTA..e.t.c which is 60 gb   and I can't see the main partition in disk utility plus I have no startup disk. Terminal's sudo command is also not working, is there anything I can do to gain root and erase all partitions?..it is still in recovery mode

Comment: Are you looking for an answer saying to follow this guide or did you reach a roadblock on a specific step? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904

Answer (score -1):

Used Internet Recovery <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and it worked fine. If you're interested you can buy a Apple technician's disk and boot from it  or buy a new Mac or do something simpler like installing Deb on a Mac with a damaged boot partition.

Comment: Where would one find the "Apple technician's disk" to purchase.? "Just buy a new Mac" is quite an expensive fix.  Finally, why would installing Debian Linux be simpler  to fix a damaged boot partition?